# Searching 360 degree videos using YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find 360 degree video from YouTube using YouTube Data API.

I'm using search keywords such as 360, VR ....

However, there are none-360-degree video in the search results.

How can I find whether a video is 360 degree format or not?

Moreover, Is there more efficient way to find all 360 degree videos from YouTube?

Comment: This is not direct answer, but may solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011893/3254912